# python3 -- RAM usage (htop and tracemalloc give different values)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ram, htop, tracemalloc

I have a code where I need to save RAM usage so I've been tracing RAM usage through `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory`. However, I have found that what `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory` gives is very different from the RAM usage I see through `htop`. In particular, the usage appearing in `htop` is more than twice than the usage returned by `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory[1]` (which is supposed to return the `peak` value). I wonder why this is happening, and what would be a more accurate way to trace RAM usage other than `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory`?

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
python version: 3.7.15

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that tracemalloc only traces memory usage of Python objects that have been allocated through Python's memory manager, so it may not accurately reflect memory usage of other resources like file handles or sockets. Additionally, tracemalloc only tracks memory usage of the current process, so it does not account for memory used by child processes or other system resources.